# Working on if else functions with class but cant use a variable in elif function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I am trying to create a id via class but i have a function called showPersonel that shows id. Program keeps saying personel1 is not defined so how can i do?

```
    import os

class personel:
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,age,position):
        self.firstName=firstName
        self.lastName=lastName
        self.age=age
        self.position=position
    def personelPrint(self):
        print("Personelin ismi:",self.firstName)
        print("Personelin soyadı:",self.lastName)
        print("Personelin yaşı:",self.age)
        print("Personelin pozisyonu:",self.position)

print("="*30)
print("="*13,"Menü","="*13)
print("="*30)
print()
print("Personel kaydı oluştur. (newPersonel)")
print("Personel görüntüle. (showPersonel)")
print()

menuAnswer=input()

if menuAnswer == "newPersonel":
    personel1 = personel(input("Personel ismi giriniz: "),input("Personel soyadını giriniz: "),input("Personel yaşını giriniz: "),input("Personel pozisyonunu giriniz:"))

elif menuAnswer == "showPersonel":
    personel.personelPrint(personel1)
```

Comment: Read about code flow.

Comment: There is no loop. Your program gets 1 input to decide what to do. With 1 input you create a variable , the input option uses that variable. Explain to me how that should work  ....

Comment: You haven't given that variable a value at that point, so you can't do anything with it.

Comment: ```personal1``` is defined **only** if ```menuAnswer``` is equal to ```newPersonal```.

Comment: First do some study about loops , posting on stackflow and getting answers won't help you. All the best.

Comment: personal1 is declared under a condition. If the condition is not True - it is not declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code which are addressed in the comments.

```
import os

# Class name should be CamelCase, Personel not personel
class Personel:
    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None, age=None, position=None):
        self.firstName=firstName
        self.lastName=lastName
        self.age=age
        self.position=position

    def personelPrint(self):
        print("Personelin ismi:",self.firstName)
        print("Personelin soyadı:",self.lastName)
        print("Personelin yaşı:",self.age)
        print("Personelin pozisyonu:",self.position)

# An empty list to store the objects
personel_list = []

# Initialise the menuAnswer
menuAnswer = None

# Loop until menuAnswer is 'exit'
while (menuAnswer != 'exit'):
    print("="*30)
    print("="*13,"Menü","="*13)
    print("="*30)
    print()
    print("Personel kaydı oluştur. (newPersonel)")
    print("Personel görüntüle. (showPersonel)")
    print("Exit. (exit)")
    print()

    menuAnswer = input()

    if menuAnswer == "newPersonel":
        # Add a new Personel object to the list
        personel_list.append(Personel(input("Personel ismi giriniz: "),input("Personel soyadını giriniz: "),input("Personel yaşını giriniz: "),input("Personel pozisyonunu giriniz:")))
    elif menuAnswer == "showPersonel":
        # Display the list of Personel entries
        for person in personel_list:
            person.personelPrint()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand well from your code. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
menuAnswer=input()

if menuAnswer == "newPersonel":
    personel1 = personel(input("Personel ismi giriniz: "),input("Personel soyadını giriniz: "),input("Personel yaşını giriniz: "),input("Personel pozisyonunu giriniz:"))
```

menuAnswer can only get one input, when it gets newPersonel, it creates personel1 object but when it gets showPersonel, the program has not created personel1

```
elif menuAnswer == "showPersonel":
    personel.personelPrint(personel1)
```

You should give newPersonel everytime for this to work

Comment: I understand the problem thank you very much I am going to be careful next time.